# Raw SQL to Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Because I'm newer to Rails than I am SQL, I took a shortcut in order to build a fairly complicated (to me, anyways) query.

Good news: I have the query working

Bad news: I'm stuck with hackish code AND can't figure out how to drop dynamic variables into it (which should be easy if it as in Rails-friendly format).

Here's my query (broken up for ease of reading):

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all( "SELECT DISTINCT ps.* FROM merchants merch, product_sales ps, users u, user_merchant_relations umr, memberships m`

`INNER JOIN marketing_efforts me ON me.id = ps.marketing_effort_id`

`LEFT OUTER JOIN member_sales ms ON me.id = ms.marketing_effort_id`

`LEFT OUTER JOIN crm_sales cs ON me.id = cs.marketing_effort_id`

`WHERE ((me.start < '2013-05-26' AND me.end > '2013-05-26') OR (me.start < '2013-05-26' AND me.end IS NULL)) AND (me.num_avail IS NULL OR me.num_avail > 0) AND (me.gender IS NULL OR me.gender = u.gender OR u.gender IS NULL) AND ((u.birthdate > me.birthdate_start AND u.birthdate < me.birthdate_end) OR (u.birthdate > me.birthdate_start AND me.birthdate_end IS NULL) OR (me.birthdate_start IS NULL AND me.birthdate_end IS NULL) OR u.birthdate IS NULL) AND ((ms.member_id = m.member_id AND m.user_id = u.id) OR ms.member_id IS NULL) AND (cs.crm_tier_id = umr.crm_tier_id OR cs.crm_tier_id IS NULL) AND u.id = 3 AND merch.id = 1")`

Anywhere '2013-05-26' appears I need to drop in Time.now.  The u.id and merch.id at the very end also need to accept variables.

I thought I could simply do: .S=?...Q=?....L=?...", value, value, value) but that's not working.

**Update**

I'm here:

`ProductSale.joins('INNER JOIN marketing_efforts ON marketing_efforts.id = product_sales.marketing_effort_id').joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN member_sales ON marketing_efforts.id = member_sales.marketing_effort_id').joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN crm_sales ON marketing_efforts.id = crm_sales.marketing_effort_id')`

So I'm taking care of all the joins, but the problem I'm running into is that, with the raw SQL, I could easily define all the tables I need to access ... e.g.:

`FROM merchants merch, product_sales ps, users u, user_merchant_relations umr, memberships m`

Whereas I'm not sure how to do this with Rails.  As a result, I just get `FROM product_sales` :

`ProductSale Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "product_sales".* FROM "product_sales" INNER JOIN ....`

So when I try to say, for example, `users.id = 1` I get:

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.id:`

Any thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: woaw, I feel you dude :(. good luck. You may want to use `.include()`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the best way of doing it, but it works and solved the main issue (inability to pass dynamic variables):

`ProductSale.find_by_sql [ " QUE=?...R=?..Y=? ", value, value, value]`